# Progress Bar Login in Powershell Delete Task

Tags: powershell, loops, logic, progress-bar

Good afternoon Stack Community,
I'm new to progress bar displays in PS. But after reviewing the documentation and a few forums I've ended up with the script below. It just doesn't do anything. It does not delete the folder/subfolders, nor does it display a progress bar, nor does it error out. Is my logic out of context or is there a better way to nest the progress bar with the associated task?

```
$computerlist = get-content -path c:\scripts\Computerlist-test.txt
$FolderPath = "c$\IT\9.0.0"
$Path = "\\$computer\$FolderPath"

foreach ($computer in $computerlist) {
for ($i = 1; $i -lt $ListOfFiles.count; $i++) { 
    Write-Progress -Activity 'Deleting Folders/Files...' -Status $ListOfFiles[$i].FullName -PercentComplete ($i / ($ListOfFiles.Count*100))
        Remove-Item -path $Path -Recurse -WhatIf
        $ListOfFiles = Get-ChildItem -Path $Path -Recurse | Where-Object {!$_.PSIsContainer}
 }
}
```

The remove-item portion works without the secondary "I" loop for the taskbar so I am assuming this is illogical.

Comment: "Loop for as many times as there are files in ListOfFiles" -> there are no files in ListOfFiles when the script starts -> it does not ever loop -> it does not populate ListOfFiles -> script does nothing.

Comment: Even if it did work, your `Remove-Item` is trying to remove the entire path, so if it has 100 items, you will remove the entire path once, with a misleading progress bar, wait a long time for that to happen, then throw 99 "path not found" errors.

Comment: Personally, I would rather get the remote machine to do the delete, rather than doing the file operations over the (slower) network link. If you have PS Remoting, then do all the computers in one command -> `invoke-command -computername $computerList -ScriptBlock { remove-item c:\it\9.0.0.0 }` and then it will do them all in parallel with the work staying local to the machines, which will be much faster overall. Except, then very difficult to get useful progress bars.

Comment: @TessellatingHeckler unfortunately it's a very secure environment due to the specific company. PS Remoting and WMR services are disabled. 

Can you possibly throw a thought out on a way to display the progress bar? If not I can simply run it blindly but with the number of servers it would be significantly more helpful to have a progress estimate.

Thank you for your first post. Makes sense.

Comment: Not sure how much agreement you'll get with "we disable the newer, more auditable, more granular protocol requiring fewer ports, and instead have wide open admin shares, RPC, SMB ports, because security", but anyway. It depends what you want - if there's not many files, the progress bar will go so quickly there's not much point, and if there are a lot of files, getting the list of them will take so long it will be annoying to wait for. I'd be tempted to do the progress bar based on % of servers done, if there are enough servers; is it always the same folder with the same file count inside?

Comment: On PS Remoting ( https://www.reddit.com/r/PowerShell/comments/7laoby/does_enabling_psremoting_have_any_security_risks/ ). Problem with doing it by list of files is that if you want to remove individual files so you can track the progress, then you'll be left with a directory tree of empty directories to delete at the end. If you just remove the folders and all subfolders, you can't see the progress of the command.